# How to specify a preprocessor directive in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse

How are preprocessor directives specified in eclipse for different configurations? For instance if I have multiple mains that should be run in different configurations and specify

```
#ifdef Problem1
//main func
#endif /*Problem1*/
```

*Note that this is with managed makefiles*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_general_pns_sym.htm) points to *"C/C++ Project Properties"* → *"Paths and Symbols"* → *"Symbols"*.

However, usually it is better to use different source files for different configurations/architectures/... instead of extensive preprocessor usage.

Comment: I was planning on using different source files, but I cannot have multiple mains in the build. Is there a better way to specify which main function or file is used?

Comment: @Adam: I was thinking of only including specific source files with different mains in the build depending on the configuration. I don't have Eclipse here now, but "exclude resource from build" [here](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_fileprop_toolsettings.htm) according to the configuration should do it.

Comment: Sadly, this information is 11 years old now. The latest Eclipse menu tree is different. I've looked all through it and cannot find a setting for this.