# error: iostream.h due to including cplex

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04, linear-programming, cplex

I am trying to use cplex in eclipse in Ubuntu 12.04 but when I include ilocplex.h I get the following error

```
/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio124/concert/include/ilconcert/ilosys.h:360:22: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory
```

The only two includes are written as follows:

```
#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
#include <iostream>
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the time ILOG's Concert library was first released, the older iostream.h headers were still common in C++ compilers, but it supports the standard iostream libraries.  To use the standard headers and libraries, you need to define the [IL_STD](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21399983) preprocessor symbol.  Instructions for defining preprocessor directives in Eclipse/C++ can be found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747147/how-to-specify-a-preprocessor-directive-in-eclipse).

Comment: Thank you! 
I just want to point out that you don't need to specify any value when creating symbol IL_STD

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the manual again or look again at the samples. Cplex has supported both the old style iostream.h and the newer C++ iostream standard for at least a decade. I just don't have the manual with me right now to give the full reference.

Comment: Actually I didn't find a solution in this manual `http://www-eio.upc.edu/lceio/manuals/cplex-11/pdf/refcppcplex.pdf` but I tried adding `-DIL_STD` to the compiler options and defining `#define IL_STD` before including the file. Now the error is gone, but I am not able to use the classes such as `IloEnv` yet.

Comment: Finally I found the solution here: `http://www.cristianonattero.com/blog/2012/05/18/cplex-in-c-using-eclipse-under-linux-ubuntu/` Thanks for your advice.