# Error due to iostream.h in CPLEX

Tags: c++, r, cplex

I have successfully installed CPLEX 12.8.0 on my Mac, which runs High Sierra. I used the R package `cplexAPI`, which actually uses the C API behind the scene, for a linear programming problem, and it worked totally fine. Now I want to use the C++ API; I'm already using Rcpp to generate the very large constraint matrix anyway so I don't want intermediate objects in R before the entire linear programming problem is solved. I told the compiler (I use the clang4 from CRAN) where the header files and libraries of both CPLEX and Concert are (by 
`PKG_CXXFLAGS=-I/<path to CPLEX>/include -I/<path to concert>/include`
 and
`PKG_LIBS=-L/<path to CPLEX>/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic -lcplex -lcplexdistmip -lilocplex -L/<path to concert>/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic -lconcert`
 in the .R/Makevars file), and the compiler successfully found them. I just compiled a cpp file in RStudio that has `#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>`. Then I got this error:

```
/Applications/CPLEX_Studio128/concert/include/ilconcert/ilosys.h:391:10: fatal error: 'iostream.h' file not found
#include <iostream.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

That's not apparently my, R, RStudio, or Rcpp's fault - it's a problem with a Concert header file. I then opened that file; it has lots of if statements, and has `#include <iostream>`, which works. Somehow it just directed me to `#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>`. It could also be the `-DIL_STD` preprocessor directive. I read in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411260/error-iostream-h-due-to-including-cplex/22421754#22421754) that `IL_STD` could be why. However, I don't know how to set that up for R, so how to do that? Is there something in .R/Makevars for that? OK, I don't know much C++. Thanks a lot.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] viridis_0.5.0        viridisLite_0.3.0    rhdf5_2.22.0         RcppParallel_4.3.20 
[5] profvis_0.3.4        microbenchmark_1.4-4 data.table_1.10.4-3  doParallel_1.0.11   
[9] iterators_1.0.9      foreach_1.4.4        cplexAPI_1.3.3       Matrix_1.2-12       
[13] Rcpp_0.12.15         RevoUtils_10.0.7    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] pillar_1.1.0     compiler_3.4.3   plyr_1.8.4       base64enc_0.1-3  tools_3.4.3     
[6] zlibbioc_1.24.0  digest_0.6.15    jsonlite_1.5     evaluate_0.10.1  tibble_1.4.2    
[11] gtable_0.2.0     lattice_0.20-35  rlang_0.1.6      yaml_2.1.16      gridExtra_2.3   
[16] stringr_1.2.0    knitr_1.19       htmlwidgets_1.0  rprojroot_1.3-2  grid_3.4.3      
[21] rmarkdown_1.8    ggplot2_2.2.1    magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.2  scales_0.5.0    
[26] codetools_0.2-15 htmltools_0.3.6  colorspace_1.3-2 stringi_1.1.6    lazyeval_0.2.1  
[31] munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: As best as I can tell, this has nothing to do with Rcpp so I will remove the tag.

Comment: This question was cross-posted [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=346c9480-1cd7-4be9-a71f-7a6068c86a60&ps=25).

Comment: Yes, I posted that on the IBM forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just define `IL_STD` in your Rcpp code before including `ilcplex/ilocplex.h`.

Alternatively, you can include `-DIL_STD` in your definition of `PKG_CXXFLAGS`.